# How do I download videos off youtube that won't download with downloadhelper?

Tags: video, flash, downloads, youtube, mp4

Some videos on youtube wont download with the downloadhelper add-on I'd like to know a downloader in the add-ons that is able to grab ALL youtube videos preferably not one that needs to be installed with terminal I tried to install clipgrabber unsuccessfully so something with less hassle would be nice

Answer (score 2):

Why not a terminal. This is not rocket science. You will not be happy with Linux, if you never want to use a terminal.

---

You could use youtube-dl. Open a terminal an run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

For a GUI:

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dlg
```

Run the GUI version from the dash.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you might want to try youtube-dl its pretty owesome. Grab a copy from their site or use your package inataller manager and search for it.

```
 #On Debian based systems.
 sudo apt-get install youtube-dl 
 youtube-dl <url of playing video/audio>
 man youtube-dl #for details
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a great browser script, which works with [GreaseMonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/).

It is called **YouTube Links.**
It is available [here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/5566-youtube-links) ([archived](http://archive.li/APGlv#7%25)).
And here is the [source code](http://web.archive.org/web/20190216031759/https://greasyfork.org/scripts/5566-youtube-links/code/YouTube%20Links.user.js).

I have chosen it, because it works without derouting to an external downloading webapp.

[image]